# Tree control in a wizard: scroll page or scroll wizard content

Tags: gui-design

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuN4YM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Context:

- Desktop web app
- Wizard (multi-page form) with three steps

  - Appears in modal dialog
- First step has only one control: tree selector

  - Tree does not fit on screen
- Two buttons at the bottom of the form: [Next>] and [Cancel]

Since the tree does not fit in the screen, would it be better to:

a) scroll the entire page - as a consequence you won't see the buttons on the form without scrolling - OR -

b) scroll the control and always keep the buttons on screen?

There's a debate between a colleague and myself. He prefers a) using the argument "people scroll" -- there are several articles online arguing for the point. However, I feel that 1) scrolling is more suited for web **pages**  (consuming content) rather than web **apps** and 2) in this particular case showing all the content at once (including buttons) makes the UI more understandable at a glance. Design choice a) makes the user wonder what lies below the fold.

Opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you (version B) because of what you mentioned about the buttons. It makes it clear there's a next step or an option to cancel the process.

Also, option A forces users to scroll down even if their file is located in the first few folders already visible. That's an annoying thing.